# The filter shows the wrong items on Android

Tags: java, android, gridview, filter

I am developing a film application for Android. I have a problem. I tried to see it on the internet because there are some solutions but nothing worked. My problem is this: I try to filter the list by the letter "W" and my array is filled with 2 items. But in my application, it displays one of the wrong items.

My code:

> MovieListMoreFragment.class

```
public class MovieListMoreFragment extends Fragment implements OnMovieListener{

//ViewBinding
private MovieListMoreFragmentBinding movieListMoreFragmentBinding;
//ViewModel
private MovieListMoreViewModel movieListMoreViewModel;
//Adapter
private GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    movieListMoreFragmentBinding = MovieListMoreFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);

    movieListMoreViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MovieListMoreViewModel.class);

    //configure gridView
    configureGridView();

    //Calling the observer
    observerAllMoviesChange();

    //configure searchView
    configureSearchView();

   
    movieListMoreViewModel.getMoviesPagination(28);
    

    return movieListMoreFragmentBinding.getRoot();
}


//observer
private void observerAllMoviesChange() {
    movieListMoreViewModel.getAllMovies().observe(requireActivity(), new Observer<List<MovieModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<MovieModel> movieModels) {
            if(movieModels!=null) {
                    gridViewAdapter.movies = movieModels;

                    if(GridViewAdapter.allMovies.size() >0)
                        GridViewAdapter.allMovies.clear();

                    GridViewAdapter.allMovies.addAll(gridViewAdapter.movies);
                    gridViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

    });
}

//configure GridView
private void configureGridView() {
    gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this);
    movieListMoreFragmentBinding.gridview.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);

    movieListMoreFragmentBinding.gridview.setOnScrollListener(this);
}

//configure searchView
private void configureSearchView() {
    //search movie
    movieListMoreFragmentBinding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            gridViewAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

//when user clicks on the movie
@Override
public void onMovieClick(MovieModel movie) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("movie", movie);
    Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.movieDetailsFragment,bundle);

}

}
```

> GridViewAdapter.class

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

public List<MovieModel> movies;
private OnMovieListener onMovieListener;
public static ArrayList<MovieModel> allMovies =  new ArrayList<>();
private static final int DISPLAY_MORELIST = 1;
private static final int DISPLAY_WATCHLIST = 2;
private static final int DISPLAY_SIMILARLIST = 3;

public GridViewAdapter(OnMovieListener onMovieListener){
    this.onMovieListener = onMovieListener;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return (movies != null ? movies.size() : 0);
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return movies.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position){return position;}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        MovieListItemBinding movieListItemBinding = MovieListItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater);

        convertView = movieListItemBinding.getRoot();

        Glide.with(movieListItemBinding.image).load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + movies.get(position).getPoster_path())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.movie).into(movieListItemBinding.image);

        movieListItemBinding.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int itemViewType = getItemViewType(position);

                if(itemViewType == DISPLAY_MORELIST) {
                    if (movies.size() == allMovies.size()) //whether the user clicked on the movie while filtering... when filtering the movies will be updated
                        onMovieListener.onMovieClick(movies.get(position));
                    else {
                        onMovieListener.onMovieClick(allMovies.get(position));
                    }
                }
                else
                    onMovieListener.onMovieClick(movies.get(position));
            }
        });
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   if(Variables.WATCHLIST)
       return DISPLAY_WATCHLIST;
  if(Variables.DISPLAY_SIMILARLIST)
       return DISPLAY_SIMILARLIST;
  else
      return DISPLAY_MORELIST;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return filter;
}

Filter filter = new Filter() {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence newText) {

        List<MovieModel> filteredMovies = new ArrayList<>();

        if (newText == null || newText.length() == 0) {
            filteredMovies.addAll(GridViewAdapter.allMovies);
        } else {
            for (MovieModel m : GridViewAdapter.allMovies) {
                if (m.getOriginal_title().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    filteredMovies.add(m);
                }
            }
        }


        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        filterResults.values = filteredMovies;
        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        movies.clear();
        movies.addAll((Collection<? extends MovieModel>) filterResults.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

}
```

> My problem:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Faced Similar Problem In My Project (Updating Adapter Content)
the problem in view Binding As [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) You Can You View Binding In Activities And Fragment There's No Example To Use In Adapters, I Know You Can Still Use It And Will Display The Correct Content
BUT You Will Face A Problem When Updating It's Content It Will ONLY Update The Last Item, Try A different Word You Wil Notice That The Last Item Is the only one Displayed Correctly
I  Don't Know The Exact Reason I Guess That when inflating each card the view binding changes it's reference Until the last item and keep it's refence to it
**The Solution**
Do Not Use View Binding in Adapter Class, Use `findViewById();`

Comment: Hi. I tested. The problem was in the ViewBinding. Thank you so much

Comment: Change
`MovieListItemBinding movieListItemBinding = MovieListItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater);`
`
To 
`MovieListItemBinding movieListItemBinding = MovieListItemBinding.bind(convertView);`
Please Tell Me If it worked To Update The Answer

Comment: Hi. It didn't work. But using findById works well

Answer (score 0):

When you set the Glide, set it to null first as the views are being reused.